# Problems with Redirection in Cypress for a Vue 3 SPA Exclusively on GitHub Actions CI

Tags: continuous-integration, vuejs3, github-actions, cypress

I'm experiencing issues with testing routing in a Single Page Application (SPA) using Cypress, specifically when running tests in a Continuous Integration (CI) environment. Despite the fact that tests run smoothly on my local machine and with Cypress locally, I face inconsistencies and failures when they are executed in CI.

Let's consider two links in a view:

```
<a id="id_example" href="/en/example/example2">content</a>

<router-link id="id_example_v2" to="/en/example/example2">
  content
</router-link>
```

If in my Cypress test I do:

```
cy.get('#id_example').click();
```

and then check for redirection:

```
cy.wait(10000);
cy.then(() => {
  cy.get('a.bg-info').should('be.visible');
  cy.location('pathname').should('include', 'example/example2');
});
```

the test passes fine, the redirection occurs as expected.

However, if I do the same thing with:

```
cy.get('#id_example_v2').click();
```

there's no redirection, and the test fails.

If I take into account that the links are the same and that this issue only occurs on CI, I'm led to believe that it must be related to the configuration of the workflow... Here is my workflow
.github/workflows/tests.yml

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Use Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: lts/*
          cache: 'npm'

      - name: Install
        run: npm install

      - name: Install Cypress Dependencies
        run: apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnss3 libasound2 libxss1 libxtst6 xauth xvfb firefox-esr
      - name: Run Cypress tests
        env:
          NODE_ENV: test
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          start: npm run dev
          browser: firefox
```

After checking, the a tag created in the DOM is the same in both cases. The only difference will be in the client-side routing handled by Vue Router.

It's impossible to achieve redirection with the router link. I repeat, this only happens on the GitHub Actions CI. Never locally, never on Cypress locally, and never with Cypress in headless mode locally.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Could someone please explain my situation or provide some insights on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Using `cy.wait(10000)` is the root cause of your flaky test is CI. The reason is the CI machine performance is dependent on spinning up and current server loading.

You may guess that the app takes less that 10 seconds to change route, based on local performance, and a percentage of the time you would be wrong.

For this reason Cypress tells us that using hard waiting times is bad practice.

[Best Practices - Unnecessary Waiting](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Unnecessary-Waiting)

> **Anti-Pattern:** Waiting for arbitrary time periods using cy.wait(Number).

Instead you should wait on the **content** within the page transition, whatever that is

> **Best Practice:** Use route aliases or assertions to guard Cypress from proceeding until an explicit condition is met.

```html
<router-link id="id_example_v2" to="/en/example/example2">
  content                                                  <-- wait for this
</router-link>
```

```js
cy.get('#id_example_v2').click()
cy.contains(<some-content>, {timeout:10_000})
```

Comment: Thank you for this relevant advice. However, the use of

cy.get('#id_example_v2').click();   
cy.contains('span', 'Return', { timeout: 10000 }).should('be.visible');
cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 10000 }).should('include', 'example/example2');

has not solved the problem. The behavior remains the same. Really strange.